# Ansible not able to execute command with sudo privileges, but the command work when launched manually

Tags: linux, macos, sudo, ansible

I'm kinda stuck on this: I'm trying to automate some task on a target MacOS machine, but the commands that need sudo work only when launched manually, and not with Ansible.
An example of a pretty simple task like:

```
- name: move brew
  become: yes
  command: mkdir /opt/homebrew
```

I also tried with the file mmodule of Ansible, but no difference:

```
- name: Create /opt/homebrew directory
  become: true
  become_user: user
  file:
    path: /opt/homebrew
    state: directory
    owner: user
    group: Domain Users
```

In both cases I get an error about permissions:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["mkdir", "/opt/homebrew"], "delta": "0:00:00.002731", "end": "2023-06-19 11:07:51.172314", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-06-19 11:07:51.169583", "stderr": "mkdir: /opt/homebrew: File exists", "stderr_lines": ["mkdir: /opt/homebrew: File exists"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "There was an issue creating /opt/homebrew2 as requested: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/opt/homebrew2'", "path": "/opt/homebrew2", "state": "absent"}
```

If I create the directory with the same command from command line it works:

```
user$ sudo mkdir /opt/homebrew2
Password:
user$
```

This is the entry for the user with `visudo`:

```
user  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xcode-select
```

I'll be grateful for any suggestion on the matter.